# How can I sum two PWM signals of different frequency with a Op Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm

I need a suggestion how to sum two PWM signals, PWM 1 + PWM 2 to an output that have them both included.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is this possible? Other suggestions?
2. What Op Amp do I need to use if I want the output handle heavy load of 12 volt? I'm going to control a large 12 DC motor and the small frequency PWM 2 is going to be the dither signal to make sure that the 12 DC motor is still in a vibrating movement. It reduces friction and makes the 12 DC motor more linear and proportional to the PWM 1 signal.

Comment: Are the signals different magnitudes? Usually PWM is an On/Off signal at a logic level (3.3V or 5V typically), your "summed" PWM looks to have intermediate values which really isn't PWM anymore, since some of the high levels look to be less than half, and some of the upper levels not really falling to something the other side would consider "low". This may be an X-Y problem... what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood something you've read.  A sum like that would not work.  You need to AND or maybe OR the two digital signals rather than adding the analog voltages.

Comment: Signals are the easiest to sum if you first convert them to a current. That sounds harder than it is, have a look at: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html

Comment: Could you provide a link to whatever gave you the idea?

Comment: AC-coupling the signals and then using a standard "mixer" arrangement might work?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes. Different amplitudes. I made this picture with Paint. I want to include noise into PWM signals to control motors and spools.

Comment: @JRE Practice. I have been controlling hydraulic with a PWM generator and these PWM generator have a tiny PWM genration included.

Comment: @pjc50 You mean a DAC?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson no, a mixer, which is what orange1234 has answered

Comment: _"I have been controlling hydraulic with a PWM generator and these PWM generator have a tiny PWM generation included."_ I suspect what you really want to do is dither a high frequency PWM to create a lower frequency variation in the PWM ratio. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/424082/could-someone-explain-dither-signal/424091

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes. I want to make the main spool viberating inside the self-resontant area.

Comment: How are PWM1 and PWM2 being generated, and what are their frequencies?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I don't know exactly what frequency I'm going to use. Perhaps 100-300 Hz. I'm using STM32 with CubeMX.

Comment: _"I don't know exactly what frequency I'm going to use. Perhaps 100-300 Hz."_ so you are only generating 1 PWM? Where is the other one coming from?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No. I'm generating two PWMs. It comes from another output from the STM32 board.

Comment: would an EXOR gate achieve what you need?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf No. Sorry. That would not help me. I'm seeking analog output :) Thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a non inverting summing amplifier.

[image: Non Inverting Summing Amplifier]

https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-transfer-function-of-the-summing-amplifier-with-n-input-signals/

You put your two input values on the (+) input. The link also provides the output equation as

[image]

If you make all the resistor values the same it should come out as Vout = V1+V2

Comment: Thats a nice sugesstion. Clean and easy. Thank you. Do you think an good old ua741 will be a good tool to use here?

Comment: I think the "good old" uA741 has not been a good tool since a few decades. Use a modern opamp.

Comment: keep in mind your pwm frequency as well, most op amps are probably fast enough to deal with the average signal but checking the op amp timings is never a bad thing

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will select another opamp. I will check the frequency.

Comment: @VladimirCravero LM358 ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson if you have difficulties choosing a part number, I suggest opening a different question. Be aware that shopping questions are not allowed here, so you can't ask "what PN do I need for this problem" but rather "what key specs should I be checking to select an opamp for this problem". Good luck!

Comment: @DanielMårtensson:  [Here's why you wouldn't use the "good old 741."](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp)

Comment: @JRE Thank you. I tried to use a ua741a opamp for a PT100 for servral weeks ago. It works, but it was very nonlinear.